# Toolset relationship widget in dynamic. Ooo not showing relationship field

Tags: wordpress, relationship

I am using Toolset to display Customer post type and I made a relationship between two post type Grants and Funders.

In toolset I have a single post template for funders in which it have a view to display Grants -> grants related to current funders.

I am trying to achieve this using dynamic. Ooo plugin and the Toolset Relationship widget have no field to set this condition.

I tried with dynamic post type widget by quering the grants, Dynamic view widget, Toolset relationship widget but I cannot achieve the result.

I searched to find solution but I can't find any solution for this thread. I contacted the support team no reply from them yet.

Please guide me how I can achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: issue resolved by dynamic.ooo team